# How to rename objects boto3 S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have about 1000 objects in S3 which named after

```
abcyearmonthday1
abcyearmonthday2
abcyearmonthday3
...
```

want to rename them to

```
abc/year/month/day/1
abc/year/month/day/2
abc/year/month/day/3
```

how could I do it through boto3. Is there easier way of doing this ?

Comment: Redundant question. Check this out. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501995/boto3-copy-object-s3

Answer (score 13):

As explained in [Boto3/S3: Renaming an object using copy_object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501995/boto3-s3-renaming-an-object-using-copy-object)

you can not rename an object in S3 you have to copy object with a new name and then delete the Old object

```py
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object('my_bucket','my_file_new').copy_from(CopySource='my_bucket/my_file_old')
s3.Object('my_bucket','my_file_old').delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not direct way to rename S3 object.
Below two steps need to perform :

1. Copy the S3 object at same location with new name.
2. Then delete the older object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (in my case I wanted to rename files generated in S3 using the Redshift UNLOAD command). I solved creating a boto3 session and then copy-deleting file by file.

Like

```py
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=my_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=my_secret_access_key).resource('s3')

# Save in a list the tuples of filenames (with prefix): [(old_s3_file_path, new_s3_file_path), ..., ()] e.g. of tuple ('prefix/old_filename.csv000', 'prefix/new_filename.csv')
s3_files_to_rename = []
s3_files_to_rename.append((old_file, new_file))

for pair in s3_files_to_rename:
    old_file = pair[0]
    new_file = pair[1]

    s3_session.Object(s3_bucket_name, new_file).copy_from(CopySource=s3_bucket_name+'/'+old_file)
    s3_session.Object(s3_bucket_name, old_file).delete()
```