# Programmatically move/rename/process files in AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS S3 structure that looks like this:

```
 bucket_1
   |
   |__folder_1
   |        |__file_1
   |        |__file_2
   |
   |__folder_2
            |__file_1
            |__file_2

bucket_2
```

And I am trying to find a "good way" (efficient and cost effective) to achieve the following:

```
 bucket_1
   |
   |__folder_1
   |        |__file_1
   |        |__file_2
   |
   |__folder_2
            |__file_1
            |__file_2

bucket_2
   |
   |__folder_1_file_1
   |__folder_2_file_1
   |__processed_file_2
```

Where:

1. `folder_1_file_1` and `folder_2_file_1` are the original two `file_1` that have been copied/renamed (prepending the folder path to the file_name) into the new bucket
2. `processed_file_2` is a file that depends on the content of the two `file_2` (e.g., if `file_2` were text files, `processed_file_2` might be a joint text file where the two original files are appended to each other-note that this is just an example).

I do have a python script that does this for me locally (copy/rename files, process the other files and move to a new folder), but I'm not sure of what tools I should use to do this on AWS, without having to download the data, process them and re-upload them.

I have done some readings, and I've seen that AWS lambda might be one way of doing this, but I'm not sure it's the ideal solution. I'm not even sure if I should keep this as a python script or I should look at other ways (I'm open to other programming languages/tools, as long as they are possibly a very good solution to my problem).

As a plus, it would be useful to have this process triggered either every N days, or when a certain threshold of files have been reached, but also a semi-automated solution (where I should manually run the script/use the tool) would be an acceptable solution.

Comment: You question is too big in scope. It looks like you're asking someone to design a solution for you. Or maybe I'm misreading the question.

Comment: Too broad, this isn't a free cloud software system design workshop.  And if you download and the upload, you're doing it way way wrong.  This is really about a 15 minute job unless you want to automate it with terraform, etc.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani Apologies if I framed my post in a misleading way and it looks like I am asking for a designed solution: this was absolutely not my intent. As I am new to cloud services, I was more interested in an answer discussing the different programmatic approaches to do this or possible programming tools to approach the problem. I believe that this would be beneficial for other readers like me, and also that it fits within the scope of SO. Quoting the SO tour page, I think my question would sit halfway between Specific programming problems and Software development tools

Comment: @MarcelloRomani coming from another community within SO (the mathematica one), I probably have different "tolerance level" of what can be posted or not here. I still haven't posted many question in the general SO channel (despite having leached info passively for many years now :) ) so I might be wrong assuming that this was an acceptable question to post here! If you think the question could be framed in a clearer/more acceptable way, please feel free to edit it/drop a suggestion here on how to improve it.

Comment: OK, so while I don't have a tried and tested solution to your problem, let me try and address some of the points (in different comments due to limits in comment length)

Comment: `As a plus, it would be useful to have this process triggered either every N days, or when a certain threshold of files have been reached`
Lambda can be triggered periodically `cron`-style in AWS. S3 can trigger lambda(s) based on certain events. Specific "trigger conditions" could be implementd in a specific Lambda that determines whethere the "rename files lambda" should run in that particular case.

Comment: `I'm not even sure if I should keep this as a python script or I should look at other ways` I usually try to find "native" ways of doing things, i.e. coding less, but Lambda + triggers go a long way towards assembling your own solution. Off top of my head I don't see much else in this case. (Other than S3 triggers + lambda)

Comment: This SO answer is relevant to your other point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492462/how-to-rename-objects-boto3-s3?lq=1

Comment: @MarcelloRomani thanks for your answers. If I'm free in the next few days, I'll see if I can find a better way to phrase my title/post so that your comments can be merged in an answer that can help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Move and Rename objects within s3 bucket using boto3]

```
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource(‘s3’)
# Copy object A as object B
s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “newpath/to/object_B.txt”).copy_from(
 CopySource=”path/to/your/object_A.txt”)
# Delete the former object A
s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “path/to/your/object_A.txt”).delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the files within the s3 bucket using the s3fs module.

```
import s3fs
path1='s3:///bucket_name/folder1/sample_file.pkl'
path2='s3:///bucket_name2/folder2/sample_file.pkl'

s3=s3fs.S3FileSystem()

s3.move(path1,path2)
```

In case if you have credentials, you could pass within the client_kwargs of S3FileSystem as shown below:

```
import s3fs
path1='s3:///bucket_name/folder1/sample_file.pkl'
path2='s3:///bucket_name/folder2/sample_file.pkl'

credentials= {}
credentials.setdefault("region_name", r_name) # mention the region
credentials.setdefault("aws_access_key_id", a_key) # mention the access_key_id
credentials.setdefault("aws_secret_access_key", s_a_key) # mention the 
secret_access_key

s3=s3fs.S3FileSystem(client_kwargs=credentials)

s3.move(path1,path2)
```