# Rename key using boto3 within the same s3 bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to re-key uploaded files so that they move from a 'temp-uploads' "folder" to a 'new-uploads' "folder.

This is my attempt thus far --- I get no error, but the files are still in 'temp-uploads'

```
  bucket = s3.Bucket(s3_bucket)
    temp_prefix = 'temp-uploads/' + packageInstance.prefix + '/'
    new_prefix = 'new-uploads/' + packageInstance.prefix + '/'
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=temp_prefix):
        old_source = {'Bucket': bucket,
                      'Key': obj.key}
        new_key = obj.key.replace(temp_prefix, new_prefix)
        new_obj = bucket.Object(new_key)
        new_obj.copy(old_source)
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't rename objects in S3. You need to copy it to a new one and delete the old one. It kind of looks like that is what you are trying to do above though. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501995/boto3-s3-renaming-an-object-using-copy-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to copy the actual file from `temp-uploads/` to `new-uploads/`, so the old file still exists in the old location.

Then, files uploaded by Django are stored as a reference in a [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield). That means Django generates an URL from a previously uploaded file. If the file is moved on the bucket outside of Django, it has no way to know it happened.