# Copy and rename a file key in s3 after being saved as one csv with prefix 'part-0000-*' with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, pyspark

After coalesce() function in pyspark(databricks), the file was saved as a single csv with a weird name that starts with part-00000 or ends with .csv extension. I would like to rename it to a more user-friendly name in a function.

I trying the approach suggested below:
https://medium.com/plusteam/move-and-rename-objects-within-an-s3-bucket-using-boto-3-58b164790b78

```
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource(‘s3’)
# Copy object A as object B
s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “newpath/to/object_B.txt”).copy_from(
 CopySource=”path/to/your/object_A.txt”)
# Delete the former object A
s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “path/to/your/object_A.txt”).delete()
```

The above code says to copy the object with the new name and delete the original file. However, after several tries, it only works when I put the whole weird name within the copy_source.

What I would like to do is since there is only one weirdly-named file, is to use the *.csv just like the way it works with pandas. I tried the endswith() function but seems to cannot work.

The answer from this [Rename Pyspark output files in s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347959/rename-pyspark-output-files-in-s3) renames each partition hence there is a obvious pattern.

```
import datetime
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for i in range(5):
    date = datetime.datetime(2019,4,29)
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print(date)
    old_date = 'file_path/FLORIDA/DATE={}/part-00000-1691d1c6-2c49-4cbe-b454-d0165a0d7bde.c000.csv'.format(date)
    print(old_date)
    date = date.replace('-','')
    new_date = 'file_path/FLORIDA/allocation_FLORIDA_{}.csv'.format(date)
    print(new_date)

    s3.Object('my_bucket', new_date).copy_from(CopySource='my_bucket/' + old_date)

    s3.Object('my_bucket', old_date).delete()
```

I think with pandas, it would have been: (note the use of *)

```
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource(‘s3’)
# Copy object A as object B
s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “newpath/to/object_B.csv”).copy_from(
 CopySource=”path/to/your/*.csv”)
# Delete the former object A
s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “path/to/your/*.csv”).delete()
```

but if used within databricks, it returns `none`

Comment: Boto3's S3 APIs only operate on full and complete names.  If you want to automate the copying based off some pattern, you'll need to list the objects in a bucket to get the object name yourself (and also, you'll need to use proper quotes)

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to integrate this to your function. Use the variables as arguments of your function:

```
bucket = 'bucket_name'
prefix = 'file/path/down/to/last/folder'
filename = 'new_filename'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)

# list the objects filtered to the prefix
for file in s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix = prefix):
  # look for the weirdly-named file after saving as one csv
  # this line below will look for the original file that ends in csv
  if file.key.endswith('.csv'):
    # copy that file
    s3.object(bucket, prefix+'/'+filename+'.csv').copy_from(bucket+'/'+file.key)
    # additionally, when you want to delete the original file
    ## but be careful with this line especially if you have more than 1 csv file as it will be deleted as well.
    s3.object(bucket, file.key).delete()
```

let me know if this does not work and we will make the changes based on the error you will get, if any.